# PHPUnit not working in PHPStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I have the following test file, an example on PHPUnit's website.

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to run it in PHPStorm 5.0, but I get the following error:

```
E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration StackTest E:\wamp\www\renting\tests\StackTest.php
Testing started at 03:37 ...

SCREAM:  Error suppression ignored for
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 166
```

Any ideas why it is going to C: when I have set the include path to E: ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it!

It seems that there was a problem with some dependency, specifically pear.symfony.com/Yaml.

Solved it by doing:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

The idea for the solution came from: [How do I correctly install PHPUnit with PEAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536668/how-do-i-correctly-install-phpunit-with-pear)

Comment: Just wanted to leave this here: [End of Life for PEAR Installation Method](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a similair issue for a quite while, that turned out to be a rights issue.

Here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22886926/1311443

Hope that it can help other people solve similair issues faster.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was similar - but i resolved this by pointing the bootstrap file from tests. Then, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct solution to JetBrains awful hack and more.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30122730/4878737