# PHPStorm 8 + PHPUnit 4.2.6 Error

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I can't make **PHPUnit 4.2.6** to work with **PHPStorm 8**.

PHPUnit is loaded as phar inside PHPStorm 8 settings.

Whenever i try to run unit test in PHPStorm i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /private/var/folders/qh/xjz1kr297v34pl6zy70_2rl00000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php(171) : eval()'d code on line 1

Call Stack:
0.0006     344584   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/qh/xjz1kr297v34pl6zy70_2rl00000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:0
0.0007     344880   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /private/var/folders/qh/xjz1kr297v34pl6zy70_2rl00000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:194


Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /private/var/folders/qh/xjz1kr297v34pl6zy70_2rl00000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php on line 49
```

When i looked into "ide-phpunit.php", i found that it tries to eval invalid code, because of invalid "substr" function usage.

So my question is, if someone managed to make PHPUnit 4.2.6 work with PHPStorm 8?

Comment: Works for me using PHPUnit 4.2.2 and PhpStorm v8.0 final running on Windows 7. Please try doing some very simple test in brand new empty project without using any "fancy" stuff (like, custom printer for phpunit etc). If it makes the difference -- maybe it something to do with phpunit.xml. Or maybe it's specific to your OS. But so far I've seen no tickets on PhpStorm's Issue Tracker about non-working PHPUnit on ANY platform.

Comment: I tried it with new simple project. And still the same. I am using PHPUnit 4.2.5.

Comment: I've just upgraded mine PHPUnit from 4.2.2 to latest 4.2.6 .. and it still works for me. I may only suggest to uninstall, re-download and then re-install PhpStorm (actual program, not settings). No other "real" ideas about what else may cause such behaviour.

Comment: I reinstalled PHPStorm, still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm generates special temporary "wrapping" to execute the tests and get the output in the form it understands better. In your case it's `/private/var/folders/qh/xjz1kr297v34pl6zy70_2rl00000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php`. Since the error says there is a syntax error, the first thing you should try is deleting it, on the next run the IDE will create the new one, hopefully without that problem.

If that doesn't help, as suggested in the comments, try downgrading the PHPUnit a few versions back, see if that helps. Alternatively try reinstalling the PhpStorm. If that doesn't work, you have better chances of finding an answer by [reporting an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) to the dev team.

Comment: Reinstall didn't help. Where i can find older version of phpunit? I can't see. On phpunit site, only the lates 4.2.6 or 3.7, but i want to try 4.1 for example.

Comment: Ok i found, where all versions can be downloaded: https://phar.phpunit.de/ Also i downgraded to 4.1.6, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Besides you can use composer and easily set the version you want. Also try updating in again a few weeks, normally such things don't remain unnoticed and get fixed sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to "unhack" the IDE to run with phpnunit.phar (4x+) nicely on windows and linux!

1. Download phpunit.phar under php, set your phar location from the IDE -> settings -> phpunit and phar location.  THEN CLOSE IDE
2. Find where your plugin files are, for php on windows this would be `:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8.0.3\plugins\php\lib`.
3. Open php.jar with winrar and open `scripts/phpunit.php`.
4. Comment out all `PHPUnit/…` require statements, so autoloader can do its job instead of using hardcoded values.
5. Go to `public static function init()` method.
6. Find the if section with a comment at the end says “awful hack”, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9hfZ.png).
7. Remove all the amateur hacky stuff and replace it with this, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3zwu.png).
8. Save the file, Winrar will prompt you to save the archive, SAVE that one too.
9. Run IDE And Run your tests, coverage. Enjoy!

Hope this helps some of you out there. I will post the information to their forums as well.

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same error, and fixed it like this:

1. Installed phpunit using: `composer global require phpunit/phpunit`
2. Goto phpstorm settings: PHPUnit
3. Select "Use custom autoloader"

   - On Windows: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\autoload.php`
   - On Linux: `/home/[username]/.composer/vendor/autoload.php`
   - Or point it to the autoloader of your composer project